# SVG icons in safari are blurred

Tags: html, ios, css, svg, safari

I have noticed that svg icons that placed via 'img' tag aren't rendered correctly in safari. They end up being all blurry. I have created a simple html page and pasted the same svg icon  multiple time using different methods :

[image]

I am a bit frustrated why does the 'img' tag lower the quality of the icon?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I have created a [demo](http://codepen.io/Goehybrid/pen/jmrZVz?editors=1100)

Comment: We can't really determine if you are doing anything wrong if you don't post an [MCVE].  If you want the best advice, do that.

Comment: Basically, you can't use drop shadow on svg imgs in Safari...?!  I tried all the workarounds suggested elsewhere (surprised this hasn't been mentioned more though), none worked, ended up just putting svg inline and it looks better.

Comment: https://github.com/artdecocode/daily-log/blob/master/shadow.md this has more info. But the workaround only works for a simple square shadow. Which you could easily use css for...

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it will be helpful for someone - Safari can't correct render IMG tag (SVG format) for retina display - so the solution is - UP size image - the result you can see here
[Demo](https://codepen.io/csscoder/pen/dyGxPBE?editors=1100)

#### Костыль для сафари (in Russian)

```
#svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 21px;

  div {
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(0.25);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    &:before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 400%;
      height: 400%;
      background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/1Le.svg);
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  }
}

.w-img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 21px;
  img {
    height: 400%;
    width: 400%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: scale(0.25);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry it's probably late but I had a similar problem and it was because of the blur filter, when I put the shadow on another element and kept the original one on top of it, it worked fine. E.g., you have to duplicate your icon element, apply shadow to it and finally place it below the actual icon.

Comment: This does not work for me. It makes it slightly clearer but the blurry element behind the clear element still makes it appear blurry...

Answer (score -2):

When you put SVG into an `<img>` tag, it basically bitmaps the vector file. So where the SVG is capable of scaling and remaining sharp at all sizes, the `<img>` tag treats it analogous to a gif and any scaling will compromise the quality of the image.

> ### [Using SVG as an img | CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-2)
>
> If I save the SVG to a file, I can use it directly in an `<img>` tag.
>
> ```
> <img src="kiwi.svg" alt="Kiwi standing on oval">
> ```
>
> In Illustrator, our artboard was 612px ✕ 502px. That's exactly how big the image will on the page, left to itself. You can change the size of it though just by selecting the img and changing its width or height, again like you could a PNG or JPG. Here's [an example](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/evcBu) of that.

So in short, by using an `<img>` tag, you lock the size of the base image. This then allows the browser to determine the quality of the image, which is going to be directly proportional to how different from the original size you are trying to display the image. In this case, as can be expected, safari is handling it less elegantly than if you displayed the SVG using another means.

Comment: An SVG embedded via an `<img>` can be perfectly sharp. It depends more on SVG and how it is used.. So IMO this answer is not very helpful.  OP should post their SVG, then we can give more specific advice.

Comment: Sure, and I could also build the image out of 60,000 1x1 pixel divs. That does not mean that it is the best course of action or the common way of doing it. Therefore, I am not going to mention it as an explanation for why an SVG is acting in a perfectly normal manner.

Comment: @amflare I'm sorry to vote down but I don't think this is correct. The problem is in using the shadow via a filter which rasterises the image and not the img tag.

Comment: The blurring happens for me using SVG tag - it's not only about using IMG tag with SVG data